# Highcharts columnrange chart with multipleseries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I want to draw a chart something like this:

[image: Expected Result]

This is the code URL for above chart:

I want to remove the space between bars as below:

[image: Current Output]

Can anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Please, add your Highcharts config to the question. Thanks!

Comment: You've not presented the URL for the code for the chart

Comment: this is the URL:https://jsfiddle.net/Loebhv43/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `groupPadding` and `pointPadding` to remove the spaces between the bars in your graph.

See the Highcharts demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-pointpadding-none/

For your graph, I made the following changes to your fiddle:

```
plotOptions: {
    series:{
        //maxPointWidth:10,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.3,
    },
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/Loebhv43/7/ to see how this looks.

[image]